# Gmail Chrome Extension and document.readyState

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am creating a chrome extension for gmail, and I have seen some odd instabilities around when certain page objects load.  Since I am trying to modify the GMAIL DOM (Customize it for my extension) it needs to be fully loaded before my initializer runs. My extension always initializes well before the DOM is fully loaded, so I need a way to have it poll until the DOM is fully formed to do its thing.

I have tried using document.readyState to poll the document so I know when to start modifying the fully-loaded DOM, but it doesn't always work.

I put into the console a printout of document.readyState polled every 100 milliseconds once the page begins to load, and I noticed that about 1/10 page loads document.readyState becomes "complete" BEFORE the DOM is fully loaded.  I can tell this because I do a jQuery selector for the GMAIL compose button and it comes up empty when this occurs, and find it as expected every other time (It finds the compose button).

Why would this be? Is there a better way to have my extension initialize script check to make sure the DOM is fully loaded before firing the DOM mods?

EDIT--
I have the script that checks document.readyState as a script injected into the UI as a content script.

Comment: If you are waiting for the compose button to appear, why don't you poll for that button instead of `document.readyState` ? There is no guaranteed relation between readyState and that button...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail website is dynamic. `readyState` / `DOMContentLoaded` and friends are all rather useless, since most of the UI is built on the fly and is not in the "initial" DOM. This is exactly what you're observing.

You need to either poll for the compose button as RobW mentioned, or watch for it being added with [`MutationObserver` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Also of note is the [`mutation-summary` library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).

Comment: To wait until an element exists for initialization, I recommend polling (with setTimeout) over MutationObservers, because it perform better.

Comment: @RobW I guess it depends on how quickly you need to react. Is it still the case that the page gets a slowdown if MOs are used even once (and are disconnected afterwards)?

Comment: Disconnected Mutation observers never slowed down (mutation events did). However, and especially when a dynamic page such as Gmail is constructed, Mutation Observers are triggered very frequently. Since the OPs goal is to eventually run some logic when the compose button is rendered, it suffices to repeatedly poll for the button. A timeout of e.g. 250ms is sufficient to detect the button in a timely fashion (in a split second).

Comment: Hey guys, this is great stuff, thanks! I ended up using a jQuery selector after I know jQuery is loaded to check for the existence of the button as you suggested, with a 100ms poll. This seems to work fine and not slow the page load down, but I am wondering why I might use a MO instead?

Comment: In the worst case (node added just after you poll), your code will wait ~100ms after the button is added. From a user perspective this is barely perceptible, but sometimes you might need immediate reaction. MOs trigger right after DOM modifications, so there's no delay. Rob's advice means that MOs will trigger _too many times_ with Gmail opening scenario, and therefore slow it down.

Answer (score -1):

Your code for `document.readyState` should be located on your content scripts.

The document referred by the background and popup pages is not the web page's.

More info here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch

Comment: My code that interacts with the gmail DOM and also uses document.readyState to know when to activate is all located in a content script. I do not use background or popup pages for this chrome extension at all.